# Where can I find Open feature form under options menu?

Tags: qgis

Going through the tutorials in the documentation for QGIS and I am stuck looking for a check box in the Options menu. The check box is labeled "Open feature form" and seems to have been moved in QGIS 2.8.

---

[image: my screen]

There isn't anything in the identify results section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option (Auto open form) has been moved to the Identify Results dock, see

[image]

Comment: yeah there isn't anything in those attributes in my data... :(

Comment: The screenshot you posted doesn't show the bottom of the identify results panel, so I cannot really judge what is there and what's not ...

Comment: Oh sorry I was thinking this was a different question I asked. Oops, I did find the auto open form thanks!